# pdoc can't import the function from other module

Tags: python, pdoc

i'm using python 2.7 and trying to gather documentation for our testing project using pdoc.

pdoc is located here:  D:\dev\Python27\Scripts
the regression project here: C:\views\md_LDB_RegressionTests_v03.1_laptop\mts\Tests\LDB\Regression\Tests
We are using proboscis for our tests and i'm trying to create html documentation for the separate group of tests, a separate python file in my case. 
I run such command:

```
D:\dev\Python27\Scripts>python pdoc --html "C:\views\md_LDB_RegressionTests_v03.
1_laptop\mts\Tests\LDB\Regression\Tests\tests\check_system_management\check_capa
bilities_encoding_problems.py"
```

and get such answer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdoc", line 458, in <module>
    module = imp.load_source('__pdoc_file_module__', fp, f)
  File "C:\views\md_LDB_RegressionTests_v03.1_laptop\mts\Tests\LDB\Regression\Te
sts\tests\check_system_management\check_capabilities_encoding_problems.py", line
 4, in <module>
    from common.builders.system_request import default_create_system, create_cap
ability
ImportError: No module named common.builders.system_request
```

pdoc can't import the function from other modules in our regression...
The structure of our project looks like this:

```
-Tests (C:\views\md_LDB_RegressionTests_v03.1_laptop\mts\Tests\LDB\Regression\Tests)
  -"common" package (with init file)
     -"builders" packege
        -system_request.py
  -"test" package
      -check_system_management package
         -check_capabilities_encoding_problems.py - this is the file i want to get documentation to
```

Of course there are lots of other packages but im not sure if it makes sense to describe all the structure now

The import part of the check_capabilities_encoding_problems.py looks like this:

```
import urllib
from hamcrest import assert_that, all_of
from proboscis import test, before_class, after_class
from common.builders.system_request import default_create_system, create_capability
from common.entity.LDBChecks import LDBChecks
```

How can i point to pdoc where to look for the functions of other modules?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When using pdoc with my Spyder IDE, I use the following script to add a directory to pdoc path

```
import pdoc
libpath = r'C:\Path\To\Module'
pdoc.import_path.append(libpath)
mod = pdoc.import_module('ModuleName')
doc = pdoc.Module(mod)
string = doc.html()
```

The `pdoc.import_path` is a list of currently used paths to look for your module; `pdoc.import_path` equals `sys.path` in default. More info can be found in [pdoc](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html) documentation.

Comment: The import_path attribute no longer exists, how is this done right now?

Comment: @ThaNoob Example here: https://github.com/mitmproxy/pdoc/blob/main/examples/library-usage/make.py

Answer (score 1):

You can set PYTHONPATH env variable. This is a path that say python where to find modules and packages by 3th party also you.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=. pdoc --html mymodule.py` did the trick. Thanks !

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=folder pdoc --html folder` also did the trick ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pydoc and pdoc read your code!!!

if you will run it from the same directory `pdoc3 --html .` or `pydoc -w .` it should work if all the modules are in the same directory. but if they are not:

make sure your main module in each directory has it sys full path append to it (to the same directory).

```
sys.path.append("D:/Coding/project/....)
```

Relative path will not do the trick!